# Как обновить сумму товара в корзине без обновления страницы?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, localstorage, jsx

Работаю с React&Redux и пытаюсь реализовать корзину. Я получаю массив с продуктами который выглядит вот так:

```
 products: [
        {
            name: "Product one",
            count: 1,
            price: 100,
        },
        {
            name: "Product two",
            count: 1,
            price: 200,
        },
    ]
```

В корзине я его вивожу.Там есть возможность увеличивать количество товара и выводит общую сумму в зависимости от того сколько единиц товара ты выбрал.
Например 2 единицы товара который стоит 100, сбоку будет общая сумма тоесть 200.
Но так как я работаю с LocalStorage, то сумма изменится только после того как я обновлю страницу.
Как можно исправить эту ошибку?
Если нужна будет более подробная информация, прошу сообщить

код корзины

```
            <div className="bucket">
                    {this.props.products.map((value,index)=>{
                        return(
                            <div className="product">
                                <h3>{value.price}</h3>
                                <div className="count">
                                    <input type="number" value={value.count} onChange={this.props.handleChange}/>
                                    <button onClick={()=>this.props.increase(value,this.props.products)}>+</button>
                                </div>
                                <h3>{value.price*value.count}</h3>
                            </div>
                        )
                    })}
            </div>
function mapStateToProps(state){
    return{
        products: state.Stack.products,
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
    return{
        handleChange: (value)=>dispatch(handleChange(value)),
        increase: (product,products)=>dispatch(increase(product,products)),
    }
}
```

Action

```
export function increase(product,products){
    return(dispatch)=>{
        products.map((value)=>{
            if(value == product){
                value.count ++;
            }
        })
        dispatch(newProducts(products));
    }
}



export function newProducts(products){
    return{
        type: NEW_PRODUCTS,
        products
    }
}
```

Reducer

```
export default function (state = initialState, action){
    switch(action.type){
        case HANDLE_CHANGE:
            return{
                ...state, value: action.value.target.value
            }
        case NEW_PRODUCTS:
            return{
                ...state, products: action.products
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

Спасибо!

Comment: Вы в localStorage храните цену? Зачем?

Comment: Цена указана в объекте продукта, а весь массив хранится в LocalStorge

Comment: А если я зайду через месяц, то смогу купить товар по старой цене из localstorage ?

Comment: Это тестовый проект и в нем я не использую базы даних.Мене интересует ответ на мой вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел ответ если кому-то нужно.
Нужно поменять релюсер на

```
        case NEW_PRODUCTS:
            return{
                ...state, products: [...action.products]
            }
```